# Colores condicionales en TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Tengo una tabla en javafx de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es cambiar el color de las celdas de la columna KmSobrepasado segun el valor que tenga. por ejemplo si el valor es mayor a 5000 debe aparecer en rojo si es menor amarillo etc.
aqui tengo el codigo que llena la tabla:

```
  @FXML
private TableView<Panel1> tblvehiculosproxmante;
private ObservableList<Panel1> infoproximos;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Panel1, String> clmnplaca;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Panel1, Number> clmnkmsobretiempo;
private Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
@FXML
private JFXButton btn_report_sobtiemp;


public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        conexion = new Conexion();
        conexion.establecerConexion();

    infoproximos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Panel1.mostrarVehiculosProxMante(conexion.getConnection(), infoproximos);
    tblvehiculosproxmante.setItems(infoproximos);

    clmnplaca.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Panel1, String>("placa")
    );
    clmnkmsobretiempo.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Panel1, Number>("kmsobretiempo")
    );
    tblvehiculosproxmante.setItems(infoproximos);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicarlo a cualquier tipo de columna. Para este caso mi columna es un string pero puedes convertirlo en un entero y hacer los condicionales que desees pero en esencia es lo mismo en toda la estructura.

```
public void modificarCelda(TableColumn<Modelo_Mensual, String> cedulas){ // columna de interes
    cedulas.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Modelo_Mensual, String>, TableCell<Modelo_Mensual, String>>(){ // cambiar el factor o como se va a comportar la celda
        @Override
        public TableCell<Modelo_Mensual, String> call(TableColumn<Modelo_Mensual, String> param) {

            return new TableCell<Modelo_Mensual, String>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {//actualizando la celda con los parametros de interes
                    super.updateItem(item, empty); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

                  if (item != null){ //esta es para asegurarse que haya informacion
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color:#"+item); //y se coloca el estilo de fondo segun el color que mencione la celda
                        //-fx-background-color:#f0f8ff //este es un ejemplo de como debe quedar.
                 }

                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

[Código de colores](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)